# javascript resources giving 403 forbidden errors in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-403

I'm working on a WordPress website using woocommerce , everything was working till the site started to show a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)' error on JavaScript resources. Other resources are being loaded correctly. I have checked the file permissions in my folders and they are ok.
[image: This is the Error messages from the console]

What could be the reason for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What server are you using? Apache/nginx?

Comment: Did you modify the .htaccess or installed any plugin (like caching ecc..) that did that for you?

Comment: I am using Apache,, and No i did not modify the .htaccess. I did not install any other new plugin,, deleted woocommerce folder and it with an earlier backup,,